# insert new data into db using php and mysql

Tags: php

```
<?php     


class appointmentOperations{

private $con;

// constructor
function __construct() {
    require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/DbConnect.php';
    // connecting to database
    $db = new DbConnect();
    $this->con = $db->connect();
}

//CRUD --> Create

public function createAppointment ($doctor, $mom, $place, $time, $date){

      $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `appointment` (`appointmentid`,`doctor`, `mom`, `place`, `time`, `date`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
       //bind parameter to sql query
        $stmt->bind_param("sssss",$doctor,$mom,$place,$time,$date);
        //execute query
        if ($stmt->execute()){
            //user insert in db
           return a;

        }else{

           return b;
          }

    }  
}     


?>
```

this question might already been asked many times but all the solution tht i looked can't solve the error. 
I've run the code at postman, it shows unexpected end of file, expected DOCTYPE. I already double check all the bracket and the semicolon,i've looked for the solution most of it said use proper php tag. i already done tht. but the same error happened.

am i missed anything else?

Comment: Is this a .html or .php file

Comment: Well, your insert is definitely incorrect (5 fields vs 6 values)

Comment: @clearshot66 php

Comment: @Shadow opss. sorry my mistake.. but still after i add those fields. the error are still there.

Comment: when you are `CTRL`-clicking on the `prepare` function what happens?

Comment: @aendeerei. just 2 cursor appear..blinking. but why have to CTRL-click the function?

Comment: If you click on it you should be redirected to the PHP core code definition of this function. If not, than you have a problem with namespace definitions (`namespace`, `use`) or with a call of your function on a false object. Not always, but I wanted to be sure, because I saw no namespace defs and use-es in your code.

Comment: You should also check if someting is "echo"-ed before your <!DOCTYPE html> definition in main page. This includes also to check if some headers are sent before your <!DOCTYPE html>. And check if before your <!DOCTYPE html> any chars or empty spaces are written (not permitted I think)

Comment: i don't know wht goes wrong it seems like i cannot create new function. but when i removed all the function its working.